# Integrate hardware (actuator and sensors) into ROS2 framework for automated control

Tags: ros2, hardware, automation, integration

I am new in ROS2 and robotics development with an automotive engineer - electrical background.

As I am a doing a project that requires ROS2 for integration of automated features.

I want to confirm this information as I haven't seen any source to particularly answer this (or I just being dumb)

So the moment I have finished organizing my package (with different nodes communicating via DDS), so that I would have a framework. How do I then integrate the hardware (with actuators (could use arduino for controlling) and a LiDAR) into this framework for controlling?

I have done some small research on how is this done and from there what I know and understand is:

- I have to create a customize hardware interface to communicate with ROS2
- Utilize the ros2_control package to communicate to the framework.

I want to ask if are these two methods above is correct, and if im not please correct me!

I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If real-time capability is an issue for you, then I suggest using [ros2_control](https://control.ros.org/) for your actuators and sensors (encoders, odometry etc).
For lidars there are other driver packages out there, normally you don't need this information within ros2_control but at a higher level for mapping/navigation etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!